# How to fix circular reference in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

lets say there's a list object
properties are added to this list whereas the property name is a string id, and the value is another object

```
class List {
  constructor() {
    this.list = {}
  }
  addObj(id, obj) {
    this.list[id] = obj;
    --> console.log("current list: " + JSON.stringify(this.list))
  }
}
```

the issue is that in the console, this returns `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` at the `-->` line

I understand the concept of circular references, but clearly im not understanding enough. Why can I not log/stringify `this.list`?

if id is a string "123456", and the value is `obj`, I expect `this.list` to be displayed as: 
    {
      '123456': obj
    }

Comment: How are you calling `addObj`?

Comment: `obj` is an identifier not a value, the actual value that `obj` refers to must be either the same object as `this`, or a different object that has a reference to (a reference to (a reference to (...))) `this` or some other object in that chain.

Comment: If any of the added elements contain a reference to the list itself, that would result in a circular structure, which cannot be represented as JSON.

Comment: `let l1 = new List(); l1.addObj(1, {a: 11});` current list: {"1":{"a":11}}. Works as expected .

Comment: @JohnMontgomery @ford04
implementation:
`const list = new List();`
`const obj = {p1: 'value', p2: 'value}`
`list.addObj('123456', obj)`
it does not work as expected. `addObj()` line throws the error

Comment: I ran the exact code you mentioned and did not got any error (I just need to add a ' at the end o p2: 'value'). Are you sure there is no other info you are forgetting to mention?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't "**fix**" that in a sense if you can't change the underlying data structure of the objects you store but you can wrap the serialization with try/catch to save your program from crashing if not all of them have circular references.
The reason why you get this issue is that one of the objects you pass as a second argument to `addObj` has a circular reference(s) to itself or to other objects that point to that object.
For example:

```
const obj = {prop: 42};
const anotherObj = {prop: 24};
anotherObj.someRef = obj;
obj.someRef = anotherObj;
const list = new List();
list.addObj('some', obj);
```

Consequently, we get a runtime error saying we have circular references:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'someRef' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'someRef' closes the circle
```

That's because JSON [can't serialize cyclic data structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Issue_with_JSON.stringify()_when_serializing_circular_references) by design.

If that `console.log` statement has been added just for the debugging purposes, please, don't do that and use [breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) in ChromeDevTools.

Comment: how do I display the list in the console then

Comment: You can put a breakpoint in the `addObj` method and then inspect the variables state in the scope (right panel). See details in the ChromeDevTools documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#watch

Comment: @Jim did you manage to inspect the scope of your data structure upon adding a new element to it while pausing in a breakpoint?

Comment: I don't know how to find scope, I'm not developing for browser. but while debugging, everything I expect to be in the data structure is there

Comment: I guess that solves your initial issue then because you've been trying to debug your data structure by printing a JSON serialized representation of it while breakpoint is the more efficient and less error-prone way.

Comment: I get that it might not be the best way to debug, but that doesn't help me understand why I cant simply log the contents of the object

Comment: You can't output the JSON serialized representation of an object if it has circular references, however, you can easily print it as is to the console: console.log(this.list)

Comment: For example, if we use `console.log(this.list)` while adding an item to your data structure, the output in node.js will be as follows:
`current list:  { some: { prop: 42, someRef: { prop: 24, someRef: [Circular] } } }`

Comment: I must have mis-thought the console would read that as `[Object object]`

Comment: It will if you do something like `console.log("current list: " + this.list)`. The reason is that in that case, the data structure has to be converted to a string. Since you don't specify `toString` a built-in `Object.prototype.toString` will have been called.
The solution is pretty simple - replace plus with comma, e.g. `console.log("current list", this.list)`.

Comment: Please, let us know if that solves your initial issue.

Comment: ahhh I just ran into that. logging `this.list` outputs the object, but with a string & `this.list` it throws an error. that's definitely it